# How to check a value is not listed in dropdown in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to check a specific value is not available in the dropdown (combo box). In my application, when i create a item, that item will be added in one of the drop down list. When i delete that item, the same will not be available in the drop down to select. So how to check whether the item is not available for a user to select in selenium?

Edited: Added the picture of it. This is an AngularJS DropDown.

[image: AngularJS DropDown]

Comment: Depends on how the dropdown is implemented. Is it a simple `select->option` dropdown?

Comment: can you post the code where you add and delete the select option?

Comment: The borrower will be added in a separate page as an normal add process and after that this drop down will be loaded automatically with the available borrowers. So i am not adding explicitly in drop down.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pasting the code with assumption that dropdown has been implemented using simple select method

```
String valueBeingChecked="xxxx";
int flag=0;
WebElement drpdwn=driver.findElement(by.id("DROPDOWN_ID");
Select DrpDwnSel=new Select(drpdwn);
List<WebElement> DrpDwnList=DrpDwnSel.getOptions();
  For(WebElement indElem:DrpDwnList){
      if (indElem.getText().contains(valueBeingChecked)){
         Flag=1;
         break;
         }
  }
```

Flag=0,valueBeingChecked not listed

Flag=1,valueBeingChecked listed

Comment: Why are you using an `int` when you should be using a `boolean`? You also want to exit the `for` loop when found.

Comment: @JeffC: Thank you..Added break to exit from loop after match is found. As far as using int is concerned ,it depends on individual's implementation/need however Boolean can be used too!

Comment: @prithvi394: I figured the same solution in my script but got the break logic from you. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I disagree. Something like this is not up to an individual... this is standard practice. You could use a string or array or just about anything to emulate the behavior of a boolean but there's no reason to do so when booleans exist. It requires more memory (however little) and it is harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

That is my cents. I use try catch. when the option can not be found, it updates the flag. It is faster than traveling the List.

```
    public boolean isOptionExisted(String option) {
    boolean result=true;
    try {
        
        Select selection= new Select(dropdownWebElement);
        selection.selectByVisibleText(option);
        
    }catch(Exception e) {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```